# How to mock a function call chained by properties

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am writing unit tests and was wondering if it was possible to mock the return value of the `getCurrentAccountInfo` function. I'm having issues because `getCurrentAccountInfo` is chained by `Portal.Account`

```
setAccountInfo(window: any) {
  this.accountInfo = window.Portal.Account.getCurrentAccountInfo();
}
```

I tried passing the window to my function, so I could test it, and ended up doing something like:

```
const window = jasmine.createSpyObj('window', ['getCurrentAccountInfo']);
window.getCurrentAccountInfo.and.returnValue({ name: 'My Account' });

component.setAccountInfo(window);
expect(component.accountInfo).toEqual({ name: 'My Account' });
```

But couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window` is expected to have a `Portal` property. Try this instead:

```js
const Account = jasmine.createSpyObj(
  'window.Portal.Account',
  ['getCurrentAccountInfo']
);
const expected = { name: 'My Account' };
Account.getCurrentAccountInfo.and.returnValue(expected);
const window = {
  Portal: {
    Account
  }
};

component.setAccountInfo(window);
expect(component.accountInfo).toEqual(expected);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about like this?

```
// setAccountInfo(window: any) {
//   this.accountInfo = window.Portal.Account.getCurrentAccountInfo();
// }

// if you need the old portal reference use the below line, so that the window Portal property stays the same
// const oldRef = window.Portal
window.Portal = {
    Account: {
        getCurrentAccountInfo: () => ({ name: 'My Account' }),
    }
}
component.setAccountInfo(window);

// if you need the old portal reference use the below line, so that the window Portal property stays the same
// window.Portal = oldRef
expect(component.accountInfo).toEqual({ name: 'My Account' });
```